# Continuous spectrum of operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $X=C[0,1]$ and we define

$$T\colon X\to X\quad\text{as}\quad(Tf)(t)=g(t)f(t)\quad\text{for all}\quad t\in [0,1]$$ with $g\in C[0,1]$ fixed.

I must find the continuous spectrum.

Now, if $\lambda\in  g([0,1])$, then $\lambda=g(t_0)$ for some $t_0\in [0,1]$. As a consequence we have for all $h\in\overline{\text{Ran}(T-\lambda I)}\subset X$
that $h(t_0)=0$

> **Question.** Why this implies that $\overline{\text{Ran}(T-\lambda I)}$ cannot be whole space $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with the uniform norm and so since there are continuous functions in $C([0,1])$ such that $g(t_0)>\epsilon$ you cannnot have that the image is dense, since these functions will never be in it's closure.Now let's see why this statement is true, keep in mind that we are working with the uniform metric as our norm and so for any two functions $f,g $ we have $||f-g||=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|. $ Now take an arbitary function $f$ such that $f(t_0)\geq \epsilon$ we know this is possible because we can construct such continuous function. Now for any $h\in Im(T_{\lambda})$ we will have that $h(t_0)=0$ since $\lambda=g(t_0)$, and so we will have that  $||f-h||=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-h(x)|\geq |f(t_0)-h(t_0)|=|f(t_0)|\geq\epsilon $ and so we will have that $B(f,\epsilon)\cap Im(T_{\lambda})=\emptyset$ and so we have that $f\notin cl(Im(T_{\lambda}))$ and so the image cannot be dense.

But this means that the residual spectrum is equal to the range of $g$, if you assume that $\lambda$ is not there you can show that the inverse operator is bounded since the $||(T_{\lambda}f(t))^{-1}||=||\frac{f(t)}{g(t)-\lambda}||\leq ||f||M$ where M is the maximum of the continuous function $\frac{1}{g(t)-\lambda}$ in $[0,1]$ and so $\sigma_c(T)=\emptyset$.

And assuming that $g$ is not constant you have $\sigma_p(T)=\emptyset$,and you will have that $\sigma(T)=range(g(t)).$With this result you can actually see an interesting result that for any set of the form $[a,b]$ we can find an operator $T$ such that $\sigma(T)=[a,b]$, we just need to find the appropriate function for wich to consider in the multiplication operator.

Comment: Thanks! Your your assumption is correct, but I don't understand your statement, that is, how can I prove what you said? "you cannnot have that the image is dense, since these functions will never be in it's closure."

Comment: do you mean how can you prove that the closure of the image is not the whole space ? Or is it some other part ?

Comment: Exactly this, thanks!

Comment: For a function to be in the closure of the image you need that for every open set that contains that function it has to intersect the image , and so we can work with $\epsilon$ balls , and so we need to have that $B(g,\epsilon)\cap Im(T_{\lambda}) \neq \emptyset$ but since we are using the uniform metric this means that for every point we need to be arbitary close to a function in $Im(T_{\lambda})$, but this would mean that for every $g\in C([0,1])$ , $g(t_0)=0$ wich we know it is not true.

Comment: is your function $g$ that of the post, or is it another function?

Comment: Sorry it is another function , sorry about the notation , thanks .

Comment: Please, another question: Why "but since we are using the uniform metric this means that for every point we need to be arbitary close to a function in $Im(T_\lambda$), but this would mean that for every $g\in C([0,1]) , g(t_0)=0$" ?

Comment: If we prove that $\text{Ran}(T-\lambda I)$ consist of function that vanish in $t_0$, then to be close to this the only possibility is that $g (t_0) = 0$?

Comment: since the uniform metric we are taking the supremum over the module of a function let's look at the distance between a function $f\in X$ and $h$ in the image of $T_{\lambda}$ so $||f-h||=sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-h(x)|\geq |f(t_0)-h(t_0)|=|f(t_0)|$ and there are functions such that $|f(t_0)|\geq \epsilon$ so that $||f-h||\geq \epsilon$ and so $f$ cannot be in the closure of the image $T_{\lambda}$ because $B(\epsilon,f)\cap Im(T_{\lambda})=\emptyset$.

Comment: In this reasoning where do we use the fact that $\lambda=g(t_0)$?

Comment: Could you formalize everything in the answer, I'm lost, I'm not understanding, please.

Comment: Yes sure give a couple of minues and I will write it up.